# Is it safe to use scala singleton in java web application containers?

Tags: java, scala, singleton

I know that using static singleton like that (see code below) often lead to memory leak.

```
public class Singleton {
    private static Singleton instance = new Singleton();

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    private Singleton() {
    }
}
```

I do n't know many details, but somewhere I read that static variables contains link to classloader and that's why they often do not removed by garbage collector.

But scala singleton are converted to static variables in bytecode. So is it safe to use scala singleton objects in java web application container?

Answer (score 0):

> static singleton like that (see code below) often lead to memory leak.

There is no particular reason a Singleton should result in a memory leak.

I would use in Java

```
enum Singleton { INSTANCE }
```

and in scala

```
object Singleton { }
```

> I read that static variables contains link to classloader and that's why they often do not removed by garbage collector.

The GC will clean up circularly referenced objects, so there is no reason for this to be the case.  Every object, every class has a link to the ClassLoader which loaded it.

```
ClassLoader cl = o.getClass().getClassLoader();
```

If this was a problem, a class loader would never get unloaded.